# using context and a hook within

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn how to use context and hooks properly. I had it working when everything was within on class, the minute I split it up into other classes the context couldn't be found. Here is what I attempted"

I've wrapped my app in the provider.

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import Header from 'components/Header';

class App extends React.Component { 
  constructor () {
    super();
      this.state = {
        firstName:  "Bob",
        lastName:   "Joe",
    }
  }
  const {firstName,lastName} = this.state;
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value = {{firstName,lastName}}>
      <Header/>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Then within Header, I created a Navbar function to try and use it.

```
const UserContext        =  React.createContext();

class Header extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="header">
        <NavBar/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function NavBar () {
  const {firstName,lastName} = useContext(UserContext);

  }
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <span> Hello, {firstName} {lastName} </span>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong.

When I used it all under the same page it was good.

I get the error that "firstname" is undefined. Do I have to pass it through as a state first?

Comment: There is no `UserContext` in your first block. Are they in the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either export the `UserContext` from your `App.js` file after creating it there or create a new file say, `UserContext.js`, which export the context.

From there, you need to import `UserContext` from the file where `NavBar` is declared.

And also it seems like you are missing `render()` within `App` component.

e.g.)

`UserContext.js`

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

const UserContext =  createContext();

export default UserContext;
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from 'components/Header';

import UserContext from './UserContext';

class App extends React.Component { 
  constructor () {
    super();
      this.state = {
        firstName:  "Bob",
        lastName:   "Joe",
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {firstName,lastName} = this.state;
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value = {{firstName,lastName}}>
        <Header/>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

`components/Header.js`

```
// other react imports omitted...
import UserContext from '../UserContext';

class Header extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="header">
        <NavBar/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function NavBar () {
  const {firstName,lastName} = useContext(UserContext);

  }
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <span> Hello, {firstName} {lastName} </span>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

And as a side note, pass the whole `this.state` object as value of the context instead of destructuring like `{firstName, lastName}` because it'd cause your child components re-render everytime as you are passing a new object reference.

So the recommended way is something like,

```
class App extends React.Component { 
  // ... other codes omitted for brevity

  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider value = {this.state}>
        <Header/>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```